# How to create a connection with Azure SQL Server with Informatica cloud IICS?

Tags: azure-sql-database, informatica, mssql-jdbc, informatica-cloud, iics

I tried to create IICS connection with Azure SQL Server.

[image]

But I get this error:

> The connection test failed because of the following error: Error establishing socket to host and port, Reason: Connection refused.

Does anyone know to fix this issue? I guess this error is due to Azure firewall blocking, but i don't know how to find corresponding ip address related to Informatica cloud IICS? where i can find the ip address for informtica cloud

Comment: Are host and ports whitelisted? Access works ?

Comment: need to whitelist ip address from azure sql side but cant find the ip address related to informatica cloud to enable the public address

Comment: can you pls check with the IICS admin ?

Comment: Hi @KoushikRoy, im using Informtica trial version and im the admin too. this is for learning purpose.

Comment: then make your sql server public and give it a try

Answer (score 1):

I tried to connect my Azure SQL database ti informatica cloud by giving required details

[image]

When I test the connection, I got below error:

[image]

I added `52.65.142.220` IP address of cloud in azure sql server firewall settings.

[image]

I tested the connection again after adding Ip address it xtested successfully.

[image]

You can find the IP addresses [here](https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/611041?language=en_US).